# How to Find the context record for user mode exception on X64

Tags: 64-bit, windbg

I have a user mode dump from Win 8.1/64, the dump was taken by attaching Windbg when the Wer dialogue. The .ecxr shows then ntdll!DbgBreakPoint for the Windbg injected thread. (As normal)

I have identified the thread by examine all stack, and finding the one which has :

```
# Call Site
00 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
01 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
02 kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal
03 kernel32!WerpReportFault
04 KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter
05 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart$filt$0
06 ntdll!_C_specific_handler
07 ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
08 ntdll!RtlDispatchException
09 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
10 <My faulty code which generated the exception>
```

The kvn aslo dispays a TrapFrame @ 00000000`0379ed28)

```
09 00000000`0379e900 00000000`00250bc8 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0026ca09 00000000`0379f160 00000000`0379f168 : ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+0x2e (TrapFrame @ 00000000`0379ed28)
```

Is there a way to use the trap frame to get the context record to feed into .cxr ?
Or is it other possibilities to find the exception context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see a `KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter` on the stack. That seems like a good thing to focus on.

If this were x86, you could easily get an [`EXCEPTION_POINTERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct out of the first parameter to [`KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). From there, you would have access to the [`EXCEPTION_RECORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CONTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The procedure is described in this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313109).

The same method works for x64 processes with one caveat. Due to the nature of the [x64 calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiscall#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention), it is harder to retrieve the actual argument to `KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter` since it is stored in a register rather than on the stack.

I recently found a debugger extension called [`CMKD`](http://www.codemachine.com/cmkd.html) that automates the task of hunting for the first 4 args in the x64 calling convention rather than blindly displaying stack values like `kb` and `kv`. This can be done [by hand](https://web.archive.org/web/20100310015537/analyze-v.com?p=482) but it is a rather lengthy and error-prone process -- better to let an extension take a crack at it first.

With it, you can do something like this:

```
0:000> !cmkd.stack -p
Call Stack : 15 frames
## Stack-Pointer    Return-Address   Call-Site       
[...]
03 000000aea3dae7e0 00007fff1e906b14 KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter+196 
    Parameter[0] = 000000aea3dae930
    Parameter[1] = (unknown)       
    Parameter[2] = (unknown)       
    Parameter[3] = (unknown)       
[...]
```

And, now we have an `EXCEPTION_POINTERS*` in `Parameter[0]`.

```
0:000> dt 000000ae`a3dae930 EXCEPTION_POINTERS
ConsoleApplication2!EXCEPTION_POINTERS
   +0x000 ExceptionRecord  : 0x000000ae`a3daf850 _EXCEPTION_RECORD
   +0x008 ContextRecord    : 0x000000ae`a3daf240 _CONTEXT
```

We can see in my example that a C++ exception was thrown...

```
0:000> .exr 000000ae`a3daf850
ExceptionAddress: 00007fff1bfeab78 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x0000000000000068)
   ExceptionCode: e06d7363 (C++ EH exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 4
   Parameter[0]: 0000000019930520
   Parameter[1]: 000000aea3daf9b0
   Parameter[2]: 00007ff6f50024a8
   Parameter[3]: 00007ff6f5000000
  pExceptionObject: 000000aea3daf9b0
  _s_ThrowInfo    : 00007ff6f50024a8
```

Hopefully this helps. Good luck. :)

Comment: Thank you it worked, and you have helped me a LOT:-)

Answer (score 5):

Another method fox x64 case doesn't require extension but is relying on two unstable facts:

- windbg ability to reconstruct registers for a specific frame
- the fact that WerpReportFault stores EXCEPTION_POINTERS address in rdi before passing it to WerpReportFaultInternal (it is the case at least for kernel32.dll    6.1.7601.23915 (win7sp1_ldr.170913-0600)

Exception pointer can be extracted as an rdi value of the WerpReportFault's frame:

```
0:007> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 00000000`0868dcd8 000007fe`fcf61430 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa
01 00000000`0868dce0 00000000`76fb16e3 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xe8
02 00000000`0868dde0 00000000`7702b8b5 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+0xb3
03 00000000`0868de70 00000000`7702ba37 kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal+0x215
```

```
04 00000000`0868df10 00000000`7702ba8f kernel32!WerpReportFault+0x77
```

```
05 00000000`0868df40 00000000`7702bcac kernel32!BasepReportFault+0x1f
06 00000000`0868df70 00000000`77230108 kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x1fc
07 00000000`0868e050 00000000`771c7958 ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x2025
08 00000000`0868e080 00000000`771d812d ntdll!_C_specific_handler+0x8c
09 00000000`0868e0f0 00000000`771c855f ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xd
0a 00000000`0868e120 00000000`771fbcb8 ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x45a
0b 00000000`0868e800 000007fe`fe03df54 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+0x2e
0c 00000000`0868ef00 000007fe`fe03e1b6 gdi32!pmfAllocMF+0x2b0
0d 00000000`0868ef70 000007fe`fb10a646 gdi32!GetEnhMetaFileW+0x32
0e 00000000`0868efb0 000007fe`fb0c4959 GdiPlus!GpMetafile::GpMetafile+0x1c6
0f 00000000`0868f150 00000001`40001c35 GdiPlus!GdipCreateBitmapFromFile+0xc5

0:007> .frame /r 04
    04 00000000`0868df10 00000000`7702ba8f kernel32!WerpReportFault+0x77
    rax=00000000c0000001 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000002660000
```

```
    rdx=0000000000000001 rsi=0000000000000001 rdi=000000000868e0b0
```

```
    rip=000000007702ba37 rsp=000000000868df10 rbp=000000000868ff90
     r8=000000000868d3f8  r9=000000000868d560 r10=0000000000000000
    r11=0000000000000246 r12=000000000868e0b0 r13=0000000000000000
    r14=0000000000000002 r15=0000000000000000
    iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
    cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000244
    kernel32!WerpReportFault+0x77:
    00000000`7702ba37 8b0d27ff0600    mov     ecx,dword ptr [kernel32!RestrictedUserHandle+0xc (00000000`7709b964)] ds:00000000`7709b964=00000000

0:007> .exptr 000000000868e0b0

----- Exception record at 00000000`0868ecf0:
ExceptionAddress: 000007fefe03df54 (gdi32!pmfAllocMF+0x00000000000002b0)
   ExceptionCode: c0000006 (In-page I/O error)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 3
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000002610028
   Parameter[2]: 00000000c00000be
Inpage operation failed at 0000000002610028, due to I/O error 00000000c00000be

----- Context record at 00000000`0868e800:
rax=0000000002610000 rbx=000000000e5fe7c0 rcx=0000000000006894
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=000007fefe03df54 rsp=000000000868ef00 rbp=0000000000000104
 r8=000000000868ee38  r9=0000000000000104 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000286 r12=0000000000000001 r13=000000006d9cf760
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
gdi32!pmfAllocMF+0x2b0:
000007fe`fe03df54 81782820454d46  cmp     dword ptr [rax+28h],464D4520h ds:00000000`02610028=????????
```

Answer (score 4):

I did some research and found two ways of getting it without any plugins, relying on WinDBG magic, etc.

First, invoke `k` command in WinDBG. Find a portion of stack like this:

```
Child-SP          RetAddr
00000000`0ab7d9d0 00007ff9`98baed2d exception handler
00000000`0ab7da10 00007ff9`98b16c86 ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xd
00000000`0ab7da40 00007ff9`98badc5e ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x3c6
00000000`0ab7e140 00007ff9`98b5b48a ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+0x2e
00000000`0ab7e860 00007ff9`96925531 Function that crashed
```

Now you can find what you want in local variables:

Option 1: Use `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` structure saved on stack

```
.exptr 00000000`0ab7da10 - 0x20
```

Option 2: Use `CONTEXT` and `EXCEPTION_RECORD` separately

```
.cxr 00000000`0ab7e140
.exr 00000000`0ab7e140 + @@c++(sizeof(ntdll!_CONTEXT)) + 0x20
```