# Analyzing crash minidump

Tags: .net-assembly, windbg, dump, crash-reports

I'm trying to analyze minidump that was generated when our application silently crashed.
The application is written in C#.
The minidump was generated using [Windows Error Reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps)

Here is the stack

```
[0x0]   KERNELBASE!RaiseException + 0x68   
[0x1]   orageneric12!skgesigOSCrash + 0x55   
[0x2]   orageneric12!kpeDbgProcessInit + 0x105f   
[0x3]   orageneric12!skgesigOSCrash + 0x3a7   
[0x4]   mscoreei!InternalUnhandledExceptionFilter + 0x41   
[0x5]   KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter + 0x157   
[0x6]   ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart$filt$0 + 0x38   
[0x7]   ntdll!_C_specific_handler + 0x96   
[0x8]   ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException + 0xd   
[0x9]   ntdll!RtlDispatchException + 0x373   
[0xa]   ntdll!RtlRaiseException + 0x2d9   
[0xb]   KERNELBASE!RaiseException + 0x68   
[0xc]   mscorwks!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly + 0x2ff   
[0xd]   mscorwks!JIT_Throw + 0x130   
[0xe]   0x7ffeb6fe1d8f   
[0xf]   mscorwks!FastCallFinalizeWorker + 0x6   
[0x10]   mscorwks!CompilationDomain::IsCompilationProcess + 0xcd   
[0x11]   mscorwks!MethodTable::CallFinalizer + 0xa1   
[0x12]   mscorwks!WKS::CallFinalizer + 0xf3   
[0x13]   mscorwks!SystemNative::CastCheckEachElement + 0x2b3   
[0x14]   mscorwks!SVR::gc_heap::verify_heap + 0x85d   
[0x15]   mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker + 0x9c   
[0x16]   mscorwks!ManagedThreadCallState::IsAppDomainEqual + 0x4c   
[0x17]   mscorwks!SArray<LoadTable<CORINFO_CLASS_STRUCT_ * __ptr64>::LoadEntry,1>::Append + 0x129   
[0x18]   mscorwks!EnsureComStarted + 0x99   
[0x19]   mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_NoADTransition + 0x42   
[0x1a]   mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart + 0x74   
[0x1b]   mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc + 0x78   
[0x1c]   kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x14   
[0x1d]   ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21
```

I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895848/2373706) to find the exception:

```
!cmkd.stack -p

05 000000001a5de2c0 00007fff2d98e003 KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter+157 
    Parameter[0] = 000000001a5de420
    Parameter[1] = (unknown)       
    Parameter[2] = (unknown)       
    Parameter[3] = (unknown)
```

Then I tried to get Exception pointer

```
0:002> dt 000000001a5de420 _EXCEPTION_POINTERS
ntdll!_EXCEPTION_POINTERS
   +0x000 ExceptionRecord  : 0x00000000`1a5df390 _EXCEPTION_RECORD
   +0x008 ContextRecord    : 0x00000000`1a5ded60 _CONTEXT
```

And read the exception record:

```
0:002> dx -r1 ((ntdll!_EXCEPTION_RECORD *)0x1a5df390)
((ntdll!_EXCEPTION_RECORD *)0x1a5df390)                 : 0x1a5df390 [Type: _EXCEPTION_RECORD *]
    [+0x000] ExceptionCode    : -532459699 [Type: long]
    [+0x004] ExceptionFlags   : 0x1 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x008] ExceptionRecord  : 0x0 [Type: _EXCEPTION_RECORD *]
    [+0x010] ExceptionAddress : 0x7fff2a0d6ea8 [Type: void *]
    [+0x018] NumberParameters : 0x1 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x020] ExceptionInformation [Type: unsigned __int64 [15]]
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, I don't understand what's that Exception code.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You should use `.loadby sos clr` and then `!pe` for .NET dumps.

Comment: @LexLi
I got the following
0:022> !pe
There is no current managed exception on this thread

Comment: That's because you are on thread #22. Use `!threads` to learn the managed threads, and then switch to thread n (if n=2 by running `~2s`). Once you are on the right thread `!pe` should reveal the details you want.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi. the exception is indeed in thread 2, which is an unmanaged thread, when I run the command I got the following:  0:002> !pe
The current thread is unmanaged.    Is there anyway to know which dll started this thread. in the app I have several DLL and I start a process to an external software, how to know which one is running this thread ?

Comment: Then I start to wonder what's the cause of the crash, unmanaged or managed. Can you run DebugDiag to analyze the crash dump first? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-use-debug-diagnostics-to-analyze-a-memory-dump Its report can be your starting point.

Comment: The answer linked gets WinDbg set up to show the callstack of a native exception, but isn't as helpful for managed exceptions. In case you're curious, ExceptionCode = `-532459699` = `0xE0434F4D` which is the code for all CLR exceptions. It's really puzzling to me that there's clearly a managed exception on the stack, yet `!pe` claims this isn't a managed thread.

Comment: @LexLi
Please see the photo here: https://imgur.com/ntuAHdA

does status: Failed means DebugDiag wasn't able to complete the analysis ?

Comment: @SeanCline
Would you please see https://imgur.com/ntuAHdA and tell me what do you think, I got this report using DebugDiag tool from Microsoft

Comment: Maybe just go back to WinDbg and run `~*e!pe`. This will iterate all threads and see if a managed exception is there. You can also use `!dumpheap -type Exception`.

Comment: Did you try `!analyze -v`? To jump to the thread with the exception, you can use `~#s`. The `mscorwks` part looks like .NET Framework 2.0. If you do `.loadby sos clr`, you are loading a .NET 4.0 extension. Try `.loadby sos mscorwks` instead. Debugging crash dumps with different .NET frameworks can be quite frustrating. Can you share the crash dump?

Comment: Thank you guys for your time and answers, I run  ~*e!pe and ~#s , I guess it confirmed that the exception is in thread 2 which is unmanaged, Please see attached photo here
https://imgur.com/la0MSNx  . 
Unfortunately I'm not allowed to share the crash dump

Comment: @ThomasWeller
What does it mean if the exception is in unmanaged thread ?

Comment: @dxtr: in a normal situation, it means that the thread has no managed call stack, i.e. no .NET call stack. In conclusion, there can't be a .NET exception thrown. Thus, it can't be analyzed. However, as I see this situation, you have 2 different .NET versions, which don't really know each other. `clr` may not recognize `mscorwks` as .NET and vice versa. Therefore it looks "non .NET-ish", or "unmanaged". This isn't correct, of course.

Comment: @ThomasWeller
I guess I will wait for another crash and hope the dump will be more useful

Comment: @dxtr: have you tried `.loadby sos mscorwks`? You haven't given feedback about that

Comment: Yes Sorry @ThomasWeller, I tried with both CLR and mscorwks, and got the same result. exception in Thread 2 which is unmanaged